# syntax error in perl script for linux

Tags: perl

I have written a very simple perl script for Linux to determine the current user logged on.
However I keep getting the following error when trying to run it:

```
bash: use: command not found
bash: my: command not found
bash: ./test.pl: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
bash: ./test.pl: line 9: `} else {'
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $loginName = '';

if ($^O =~ /MSWin/i)
{
$loginName = getlogin;
} else {
#else it is unix
$loginName = getpwuid($<);
}

print $loginName;
```

I have tried to google this but I dont see what I am doing wrong with my if statement? It works fine on Windows.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you are running it with bash.
Try perl test.pl

Comment: Show us how you are running your script.

Comment: Also, make sure #!/usr/bin/perl is the very first line in your script.

Comment: Ahh your right. I was invoking it wrong. I was doing . ./test.pl, should be perl test.pl. Thank you John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the script incorrectly: these errors are clearly from `bash`, while `perl` should be running the script instead.

I don't know how you're running it now, but (assuming its filename is `mywhoami`) you can always invoke `perl` explicitly:

```
perl mywhoami
```

It should also work to make it executable

```
chmod a+x mywhoami
```

and then execute it:

```
./mywhoami
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is something it the way you run the script.
Please try to run it as follow:

```
$perl <script.pl>
```

Comment: `py` is not the best extension for a Perl script, is it?

Comment: @choroba, you are right, I'm used to run python scripts (which have the same behavior), it should be .pl, thx.